# Docker php56-fpm - Call to undefined function apache_note()

Tags: php, docker

I am using docker to run PHP but my project is undefined the function `apache_note`

> Fatal Error 
> Error: Call to undefined function apache_note()

I think my PHP is missing an extension or must have the `apache_note` function enabled somewhere in php.ini, but I don't know where to fix it

In my file docker-compose.yml

```
    php-fpm:
        build: docker/php-fpm
        working_dir: /application
        volumes:
          - ./application:/application
          - ./docker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
        networks:
          testing_net:
            ipv4_address: 172.30.1.4

    webserver:
     image: 'bitnami/apache:latest'
```

In my Dockerfile

```
FROM phpdockerio/php56-fpm:latest
WORKDIR "/application"

# Fix debconf warnings upon build
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Install selected extensions and other stuff
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install  php5-mysql php5-gd \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

# Install git
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install git \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*
```

In vhost.conf

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
   SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://php-fpm:9000"
</FilesMatch>
```

Please help me, thank everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apache_note()` function is not available in PHP-FPM.

You have to run PHP as a module to use the `apache_note()` function

Comment: See also https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.apache.php

Comment: Is there a way to hack it running in conjunction with PHP-FPM? Thank your for infomation

Comment: I replaced PHP-FPM and used apache php and it works, thank you